# MATLAB inline function if statement

Tags: matlab, function, piecewise

I'm trying to define a function as follows:

```
if nn == 0
   tau(nn) = 0
else
   tau(nn) = crazy_function(nn)
end
```

However, I want to do it in a single line. I tried

```
tau = @(nn) crazy_function(nn).*(nn~=0) + 0.*(nn==0);
```

But this doesn't work because `crazy_function(0)` is not a number `(NaN)`. So MATLAB has trouble with the first part of the expression. How can I get MATLAB to simply return `0` when I call `tau(0)` by some modification of this line? Thanks!

Comment: What is the range of values of `crazy_function` for `nn != 0`?

Comment: Why does this need to be done in a single line?

Comment: Is by chance crazy_function returns an integer? if that's the case you can use: tau = @(nn) int16(crazy_function(nn)).*(nn~=0) + 0.*(nn==0); Nan is automatically converted to 0 when casting to integers.

Comment: You should really just modify `crazy_function` to return `0` when `nn = 0`

Comment: @drhagen Nice one. :)